# I am not getting the expected output while entering 10000 in this code. The problem is about converting decimal to binary

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am not getting the expected output while entering 10000 in this code. This is the code
*decimal to binary*\

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int N,sum=0,pv=1,r;
        cin>>N;
        while(N>0){
            r=N%2;
            sum= sum + r*pv;
            N=N/2;
            pv=pv*10;
        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It looks like you are reversing the bits. You are getting the lowest bits of N first, but putting them into the most significant bits of sum.

Comment: What output do you expect, and what output do you get?

Comment: When a input a large number like 10000 I'm getting output as -468756976 but expected output is 10011100010000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `unsigned long long int` type modifier to get your expected output. The value of `sum` exceeds the limit of a common integer does somehow.

Just modify your declaration:

`unsigned long long int N, sum = 0, pv, r;`

Your code with the above modification:

> **Output:**

```
10000
10011100010000
```

And you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for your help as I'm a beginner in programming

Answer (score 1):

10000<sub>10</sub> is equal to 10011100010000<sub>2</sub>.
On most architectures, `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` is 2147483647<sub>(10)</sub>, so you have an integer overflow, while calculating `sum` an `pv`.

You could use a wider type for your variables, like `unsigned long long`, which should be at least a 64-bit type, but that's not the solution. Consider that 2147483647<sub>10</sub> is equal to 1111111111111111111111111111111<sub>2</sub> and 1111111111111111111111111111111<sub>10</sub> is way bigger than 18446744073709551615<sub>10</sub>.

What you seem to forget is that `N`, beeing an `int`, has *already* a binary representation. `std::cin >> N;` has already performed the decimal to binary transformation for you. All you have to do is to extract the values of those bits.

```
// Calculate the number of bits in a int
unsigned i = sizeof(N) * CHAR_BIT - 1;

// Skip the leading zeroes, if you want 
do
{
    if ( (N >> i) & 1u)
        break;
    --i;
}
while ( i );

// Print the bits, shifting and masking the number
do
{
    std::cout << ((N >> i) & 1u);
}
while ( i-- );
std::cout << '\n';
```

Try with some negative number too, you'll probably notice that those are internally represented using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).